# How to get list of all databases in Azure DocumentDB account?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

Just started with DocumentDb, trying to build a sharding layer above multiple acoounts/databases/collections.

In .net SDK 1.5, Is there is any way to query or list all databases in certain account?

Answer (score 3):

you can take all db informations in a list, by query with (and without) condition.

```
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("yourEndPointUrl"), "yourAuthKey");
var list = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

warn: its look like dummy AsEnumerable().ToList(), but ToList() doesn't work itself dynamic type conversation reason.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `CosmosClient` in the CosmosDB sdk v4, you can retrieve all databases with the following code, where 'Id' is the name of the database:

```
var iterator = _client.GetDatabaseQueryIterator<DatabaseProperties>(cancellationToken: cancellationToken).GetAsyncEnumerator(cancellationToken);

while (await iterator.MoveNextAsync())
{
    var dbName = iterator.Current.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some Powershell Commandlets out on GitHub that were released over the summer that you can use to get a listing of all databases.

List all the Databases in the Given Azure DocumentDB Database Account

```
Import-Module PATH_TO_Module\Azrdocdb.dll
$ctx = New-Context -Uri <uri> -Key <key>
Get-databases -Context $ctx | ft
```

Here is a link to the [full article](http://www.sqlserverfaq.net/2015/07/04/releasing-powershell-cmdlets-for-azure-documentdb-in-github/)
HEre is a link to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/savjani/Azure-DocumentDB-Powershell-Cmdlets)

Comment: Actually if you look in the class file you will see the code to GetDatabases

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/documentdb-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/src/Program.cs

Line 66 - exclude the where clause.

Regarding sharding, I would strongly suggest that you use one of the partition resolvers and let the SDK handle it for you

See here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sharding/